# How to mount a LVM partition on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, mount, lvm

```
#fdisk -l

/dev/sdb1   *           1        9702    77931283+  8e  Linux LVM
```

I tried the following command:

```
#mkdir /media/backup
#mount /dev/sdb1 /media/backup

mount: unknown file system 'LVM2_member'
```

How do I mount it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [the solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=656485)

```
#pvs
/dev/sdc5 intranet lvm2 a- 372,37G 0

# lvdisplay /dev/intranet
LV Name                /dev/intranet/root

#mount /dev/intranet/root /media/backup
```

Comment: Note that on Ubuntu 14+, if you just `sudo apt-get install lvm2` and reboot, the lvm2 volume will auto mount in the file browser.

Comment: @y3sh Thanks!  My Ubuntu 17.10 system for some reason was no longer booting.  "Welcome to emergency mode!" it would print on the screen.  Used LiveCD to boot and comment out the LLVM partition in /etc/fstab, and it finally booted again.  Installed lvm2 package as you wrote, put the original entry back in fstab, everything works as it used to.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at the *scan commands, pvscan, vgscan and lvscan.  This will search for the various lvm components.  If /dev/sdb1 is a physical volume that has a volume group with a logical volume, it should show up. If lvscan produces something like:

> ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/home' [9.00 GB] inherit

Then you can mount /dev/vg00/home as /home.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a filesystem on the new device?

mkfs -j /dev/sdb1

or mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1

Comment: the "new device" is the old hard disk that were already working in another machine as the boot partition. I don't want to overwrite nothing on it

Comment: Indeed you don't.  Sorry for the assumptions...  After re-reading it is a bit more plain but I see you have the answer below.